# Where can I find a list of Yen Press shoujo ai/yuri titles?

Tags: resources

I've been building a list of the *shoujo ai/yuri* manga & light novels so that I can have an idea of where to get them and how much does they cost. On [Seven Seas Entertainment's site](http://www.sevenseasentertainment.com/tag/yuri/), they have a *yuri* tag

While not *shoujo ai/yuri*, when I added *K-On*, I was reminded about [Yen Press](http://yenpress.com/), but there's no tag system on their website. When I do a search for "yuri", I only get [*Eclair*](http://www.b2c.hachettebookgroup.com/titles/none/eclair/9781975326166/?yen). Under sub-genres, they have "Gay & Lesbian", but looking up "lesbian" returns nothing (since I'm not looking for *shounen ai/yaoi*).

Where can I find a list of Yen Press *shoujo ai/yuri* titles? This way, I can search the title up on Yen press to find where I can buy it.

**Note**: If *Eclair* is actually the only *shoujo ai/yuri* title Yen Press has localized, then a resource is still useful in case searching for "yuri" on the site fails later on.

Comment: *Eclair* isn't the only one on their site. *Ano Ko ni Kiss to Shirayuri wo* would surely qualify, and *Saki* arguably would. Probably others I'm not aware of (I don't follow licensing much). Unfortunately I couldn't find any way to do a tag-based search on their site or to search their [mangaupdates list](https://www.mangaupdates.com/publishers.html?id=279) by tag.

Answer (score -1):

- Kiss and White Lily for My Dearest Girl
- Eclair
- Cocoon Entwined
- Killing Me
- Our Wonderful Day
- Whenever Our Eyes Meet...
- Yuri Life

I know there are some series where yuri isn't the main focus but it's there, like *Scum's Wish* and *Murciélago*. And some where it's subtext, like the *K-ON* series.

Comment: I appreciate your list however this doesn't answer the question of where i can find a list as if Yen Press releases any more yuri, your answer will be out of date

Comment: Worst case, there's no existing list outside there. But at the very least, we can make (and possibly collaborate on) this answer *as the list* of Yen Press' *shoujo ai/yuri* titles...